# What is this helicopter seen in the Falcon Crest TV series?

Tags: helicopter, aircraft-identification

[image]

[image]

My next to last "Falcon Crest" related question for the database I'm programming: Does anyone recognize the make and model of this helicopter from episodes # 160 <7.05> (first screen capture) and # 163 <7.08> (second screen grab).

My guess is a Bell Jet Ranger, but I'm not sure.

Any hints are appreciated!  Thanks.

Comment: Yes it's a Jet Ranger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Looks to me like a Bell 206 JetRanger/LongRanger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_206)